# How do I save/load information onto/from my device?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm developing an application, but I need it to save its information onto the computer, and load it from there next time it's opened.

To give the simplest example: I have an array of strings and I want to save them as a *.txt file in the application's directory. And every member of the array should be on a new row of the file.
And I want to load the entries of the file into the array when I open the app, or create an empty *.txt file, if one doesn't exist.

Note: if there is an easier way to do this, instead of saving them into a *.txt, please tell me. Saving them strictly as a *.txt format isn't mandatory.

Also, I am using wxWidgets for my application, if it's gonna make it any easier.

Comment: what kind of information are you saving? SOme kind of configuration? Position/size of the windows/controls? Application data?

Comment: I'm saving the members of a listbox there.
The user can add members to this list (or will be able to, as soon as I figure out how to save/load these strings)

Comment: please re-read my question and then give the proper answer. One more time - what kind of information you want to save - Application data or some kind of configuration?

Comment: It's Application data, I guess.

Comment: well you are the developer and so you should know what kind of data is used. ;-) Now to the question - you can use SQLite to save the Application Data and then use `SELECT...` query to retrieve it. You can use standard C++ stream classes to save the string to disk and then read it - there are plenty of examples on the web and in here on SO. And if it is in fact some kind of configuration data for your application - taker a look at `wxConfig` documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MainFrame::MainFrame() {
    wxFileName f(wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath());
    wxString appPath(f.GetPath());

    std::ifstream inputFileStream;
    inputFileStream.open(std::string(appPath.mb_str(wxConvUTF8)) + "data.txt");
    std::string data;
    inputFileStream >> data;
}
MainFrame::~MainFrame()
{
    wxFileName f(wxStandardPaths::Get().GetExecutablePath());
    wxString appPath(f.GetPath());

    std::ofstream outputFileStream;
    outputFileStream.open(std::string(appPath.mb_str(wxConvUTF8)) + "data.txt");
    std::string data = "something";
    outputFileStream << data;
    outputFileStream.close();
}
```

When frame is created, I get the data. When frame is destroyed, I save the data. I don't use C++ standard library classes, but wxWidgets classes and methods for UTF-8 support. (I haven't checked if this piece of code works – it's taken from my old project.)

Comment: This worked, but I think the code itself is overly complicated. I implemented it by just using "std::ifstream input("data.txt"); std::string str; std::getline(input, str);" to get my input into a single string, and then I can use an algorithm to break it into an array. And I use "std::ofstream output("data.txt");" to save it. I don't know if there is any difference in the functionality between the version you suggested and the one I ended up using.

Comment: I think that when using some framework you should use primarily the framework's solutions (classes and methods). Also, these methods are compatible with wxString and other things in wxWidgets + UTF-8. Of course, if you don't use UTF-8 and you feel this is overly complicated, just use standard library.

Comment: You most certainly wouldn't want to save user data to the executable path. Use `GetDocumentsDir()` instead.

Comment: Also using `.mb_str(wxConvUTF8)` is wrong, because paths aren't in UTF-8 on e.g. Windows; so it won't work if the path actually contains any non-ASCII. Using `wxString path = f.GetPath() + "data.txt";` and `.open(path.fn_str())` is more likely to work as intended.

Comment: @LauriNurmi Sorry, my code was in past project intended for configuration data, not user data, but I haven't had time to correct it.

Comment: @User123 Still, the executable path would be the wrong place for configuration data, too. Often a regular user running the application wouldn't even have write access to the folder where the executable resides (e.g. `/usr/bin` or `C:\Program Files\YourApp`).

Comment: The project was meant for personal use (for me and my friend only).

Comment: @User123, those classes were made when C++ didn't have STL. Now in XXI century it is striongly advised to use C++/STL classes. The wx alternatives are there for backwards compatibility only.

Comment: @Igor Thank you! I see that you are more experienced in wxWidgets, so I'll take your word for granted. We learn something every day.